# Running a command in multiple directories

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I am running this command in one of my many subdirectories:

```
ls *.rst -C1 -t | awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm
```

Essentially, this lists all files that end with .rst and I sort them based on the time they were created and I want only the most recently created file. I then delete the rest of the *.rst files.

I have 200 directories that I need to execute this command in. I have tried using the find command to pass the location of the directories to this command but I have not been successful. All of these directories contain the files inputs.in.  I have tried:

```
find . -name inputs.in | xargs ls *.rst -C1 -t | awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm
```

but I believe since the input to the ls *.rst bit is the full path including the file name, it has not been working.

I'm sure it's quick fix but your help and comments would be greatly appreciated. I would like to run this command from the parent directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some ugly way:

```
find . -name inputs.in | xargs dirname |                     \
     xargs -I{} -n 1 find {} -name '*.rst' | xargs ls -C1 -t |    \
     awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm
```

ls with wildcard will fail because globbing happens before even find is executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
find . -name inputs.in | parallel "cd {//} && ls *.rst -C1 -t | awk 'NR>1' | xargs rm"
```

If it is not packaged for your system, this should install it in 10 seconds:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
will love you for it.